# Strange behavior of string.Join on byte array and startIndex, count

Tags: c#

I'm using string.Join to be able to show what values an array contains. I have stumbled upon a strange behavior when using a byte array and startIndex and count.

```
byte[] byteArr = new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
string[] stringArr = new string[] {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"};

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Whole byteArr: {0}",string.Join(", ", byteArr)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Whole stringArr: {0}",string.Join(", ", stringArr)));

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("0 - 5 byteArr: {0}",string.Join(", ", byteArr,0,5)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("0 - 5 stringArr: {0}",string.Join(", ", stringArr,0,5)));
```

gives this result

> Whole byteArr: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
>
> Whole stringArr: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
>
> 0 - 5 byteArr: System.Byte[], 0, 5
>
> 0 - 5 stringArr: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Why do **string.Join(", ",byteArr,0,5)** return the string **System.Byte[], 0, 5**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, you're calling this overload of the `Join` method which concatenates the elements of an object array, using the specified separator between each element.

```
public static string Join(
    string separator,
    params object[] values
)
```

not this:

```
public static string Join(
    string separator,
    string[] value,
    int startIndex,
    int count
)
```

Which concatenates the specified **elements of a string array**, using the specified separator between each element.

This is simply because the overload that takes a `startIndex` and `count` is only called if you supply a string array as the second argument to the `Join` method.

Because you're supplying an array that is not a string as the second argument to the `Join` method, it ends up called the first overload I've shown above and hence you're seeing `System.Byte[], 0, 5` because calling `ToString` on a byte array will yield a `System.Byte[]`, the `ToString` representation of `0` is `0` , `5` is `5` and therefore the result is  `System.Byte[], 0, 5`.

So how do we make sure that we call the version that accepts a `startIndex` and `count`?

If you wish to call this overload of the `Join` method, and the array you have is not a `string[]` then transform the elements of the array you have to a string array, example:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("0 - 5 byteArr: {0}", 
     string.Join(", ", byteArr.Select(b => b.ToString()).ToArray(), 0, 5)));
```

By performing `byteArr.Select(b => b.ToString()).ToArray()` we make sure that we're caling the overload with the `startIndex` and `count` parameters.

Comment: Aha! I really need to read the documentation more carefully! Thanks for pointing out my error and also providing a solution!